# Get QTableView cell value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtableview

I have a simple QTableView (not QTableWidget) with multiple rows and columns. Users can click and select single cell in my QTableView. 
this is a part of my code:

```
def __init__(self, fileName, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.gui = form_class
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.tableView.setModel(self.model)
        self.tableView.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.tableView.clicked.connect(self.fn_get_cell_Value)


def fn_get_cell_Value(self):
        model = self.tableView.model()
        data = []
        for cell in range(model.SelectedClicked):
            data.append([])
            value = str(model.data(index))
            data[row].append(value)
```

How can I get this clicked cell value. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The slot must have a parameter where the QModelIndex of the model returns, in your case the code would look like this:

```
def fn_get_cell_Value(self, index):
    datas =  index.data()
    print(datas)
```